# jquery hide/show for multiple divs/tables gone wrong on second click

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).each(function (){
     $(".issue_load").on('click',function (){
      //$('.div'+$(this).attr('target')).show();
       $(".copytab2").hide();
     });
});

$(document).each(function (){
     $("#receipt_load").on('click',function (){
        $(".copytabl").hide();
        $(".copytab2").show();
     });
}); 
<div class ="form-group recept_fetch">
<table class ="table table-condensed table-striped table-bordered table-hover copytab2">
<thead>
 <tr id = "recgridview"></tr>
</thead>
<tbody class = "recptdt">
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
<div class ="form-group fetch_request">
<table class ="table table-condensed table-striped table-bordered table-hover copytabl">
<thead>
<tr id = "gridview"></tr> 
</thead>
<tbody class = "billdt">
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

*For 1st click it was ok when on 2nd click copytabl was unable to show copytabl.Am trying to some thing like this.when i click on issue_load, .copytabl should be shown and receipt_load should show .copytab2 and again same click on issue_load show .copytabl even tried adding div same prob.*

```
<div class="form-group tblalt">
<table class = " table-striped table-bordered table-condensed header-fixed issue_load scroll" style = "width:50%" id = "request_ids">
<thead>
<tr id = "newtbl2">
<th  style = "width:44%">Indent Req No</th>
<th >Date</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody id ="cur" class = "patdetails Tbodycontent">

</tbody> 
</table>
</div>



<div class="form-group tblalt1" style = "width:85%" id = "receipt_load">

<table class = "table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed header-fixed receipt_load scroll">

<thead>
<tr id = "newtbl1">
<th>Indent Issue No</th>
<th>Date</th>
<th>Req.No</th>
<th>Date</th>                           
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody id ="recpnum" class = "patdetails Tbodycontent1 text-center">


</tbody> 
</tbody> 

</table>

</di
```

v>

Comment: its better to create a snippet of include html as well

Comment: check the updated question now

Comment: can't see elements with classes `issue_load` and `receipt_load` in your HTML. where are those?

Comment: html shown doesn't have the classes used in the script

Comment: `$(document).each(function (){` why `each` iteration on document?

Comment: sorry guys receipt_load is changed to id and check updated question.

Comment: @jai just tried to get we can use on click.